# How to search content of strings stored in XML file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, search

I'm new to android development.

I have an activity containing a bunch of fragments, each fragment shows a different text. I set the text at runtime from strings.xml (i.e tv.setText...)

Here is an example of my strings.xml:

```
<string name="string1">the content I want searched, text1</string>
<string name="string2">the content I want searched, text2</string>
<string name="string3">the content I want searched, text3</string>
```

**This is my problem:**
I want to add search functionality in the app, I want to be able to search for words inside the strings and return the whole string to the user as a result.
So for example if the user searches for text2, It would return the whole string.

I already read the search guide on android-developers here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html

I also found a bunch of tutorials, but all of them seem to deal with data stored in SQLite databases.

Here is more of my code:
searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Search" >
</searchable>
```

SearchableActivity:

```
public class SearchableActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }



    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          doMySearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

P.S Is this the best way to do this? I have a lot of strings (>1000)
I read about using databases instead but I don't know how to convert all my data into a db, and don't know how to set text from a db...etc

Answer (score 2):

I think you need search in strings.xml file with a key, if I understand you here is the answer .

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="string1">the content I want searched, text1</string>
```

method for searching inside strings.xml

```
private String SearchForString(String message){
// get the resource id if matched any key in strings 
// message Passed string you want search for
// "string" type of what you looking for
// package name

try {
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(message , "string" , getPackageName());
    String stringReturned =  getResources().getString(resId);
return stringReturned;
  } catch(Exception e){
  return null;
  }
  }
```

call method now

```
SearchForString("string1");
```

it should return:  *the content I want searched, text1*

Comment: It's a good practice to have the method name start with a lower case like `searchForString()`

Comment: I tried your solution but what it does is basically it gives you the value of the string corresponding to the id you send in `searchForString()` parameter. It doesn't do anything special.

Comment: Does not work for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62825160/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-androids-strings-xml

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using string use string-array. In resource create a file and there declare like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><resources>
<string-array name="names">
    <item>the content I want searched, text1</item>
    <item>the content I want searched, text2</item>
    <item>the content I want searched, text3</item>
</string-array>
```

now in code do the following to search the string

```
String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);
for (String s : names) {
    int i = s.indexOf(searchKeyword);
    if (i >= 0) {
        // found a match
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it in a demo app, but I seem to have some problems with this method: 1-How can I know the number of results founds. 2-How can I get the name of the item (inside the array) for the results found. 3-I managed to put the result in a custom listadapter but is there a way to configure the onclick to open the fragment which contains the text(I know this is far fetched, but I need to find a better way of implementing search in the app). I still think there must be a better way of doing all of this, can anyone else please shed a light on this issue.

Comment: if you had very basic programming knowledge you could easily solve the points you noted .. so better grow your programming skill

Comment: @stinepike But what if we are not in position to convert our `string` to `string-array`?