# How to lookup for a string translation on android?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I need to translate error codes that i receive from one of owner servers.

So, instead of having a string id i have a string, the error code, and i need to check the resources for possible translation.

How can i perform a lookup?

Comment: How does your error code map to the resources? Is the name of the resource tied to the error code?

Comment: It is not defined yet. I think a good way would be using an default language to define all codes. This way i could try to match first with that language and then look up for possible translations.

Comment: As i am reading posts, it figure that a possible way to map could use a dedicated string resource file with all codes. Then loaded and search in memory for a match. Once i have the id, getString method will do the rest.

Comment: Probably this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322075/6142219

Comment: A localize version of string array for French, for example, is just a another set of strings. I can't relate the items of one array with the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that there is a function for that, getIdentifier.

```
private String getStringResourceByName(Resources res, String aString) {
    String packageName =   App.getInstance().getPackageName();
    int resId =  App.getInstance().getResources().getIdentifier(aString, "string", packageName);
    return res.getString(resId);
}
```

Trying on a simple test:

```
@Test
public void test(){

    Resources res = serviceFactory.getApplicationContext().getResources();

    Log.d(TAG, "default language: "+ getStringResourceByName(res,"LG")); //will print the default definition.

    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = Locale.FRENCH; //for instance
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null); //

    Log.d(TAG, "French: "+ getStringResourceByName( res,"LG"));//will print definition of LG in french resource file

}
```