# How to search for a String in Android's Strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I tried this answer: [How to search content of strings stored in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321806/how-to-search-content-of-strings-stored-in-xml-file):

```
companion object {
        val TAG: String = "EffectsDescription"
        fun fromStringsXml(string: String, context: Context): String {
            val ss = string.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
            Log.d(TAG, "gonna search for " + ss);
            val s = searchForString(ss, context);
            Log.d(TAG, "found: " + s);
            return s ?: "ERROR"
        }

        private fun searchForString(message: String, context: Context): String? {
            return try {
                val resId: Int = context.resources.getIdentifier(message, "string", context.packageName)
                Resources.getSystem().getString(resId)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
        }
    }
```

and I'm calling from Java like this:

```
EffectDescription.Companion.fromStringsXml(effectOrCategory, MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext())
```

but I get `ERROR` for all variables. I'm logging them just to see if they match strings in my `strings.xml` and they do. For example I have

```
<string name="distortion">Distortion</string>
```

and it says

```
gonna search for distortion
found: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
fun fromStringsXml(string: String, context: Context): String {
            val ss = string.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");
            Log.d(TAG, "gonna search for " + ss + " with packageName " + context.packageName);
            val s = searchForString(ss, context);
            Log.d(TAG, "found: " + s);
            return s ?: "ERROR"
        }

        private fun searchForString(message: String, context: Context): String? {
            return try {
                val resId: Int = context.resources.getIdentifier(message, "string", context.packageName)
                Log.d(TAG, "redID: $resId")
                context.resources.getString(resId)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            }
        }
```